# How to chang matcaps light direction in blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, matcaps

Hey everyone so with new matcaps in blender we are getting really cools shapes! I wanted to know if I can change matcaps light direction in an easy way! because I would like to use toon maptcap as a starting point for painting! the only problem I've got is I can't react it to light direction! I know I can make toon shaders and free style which is also awesome! but toon matcap is also awesome at the same time and it's only one click! I was wondering if there is a way to make matcaps to react to lights or changing it's light direction in Blender! 
Tnx.
[image]

Comment: You can only flip matcap lighting (in 2.8). Matcaps itself are static images projected onto mesh, so no light source is involved in the process.

Comment: Is there anyway to get these matcaps as materials in Blender so that lights can affect them? I hope in future they add features to control the lighting for these matcaps as well.

Comment: Matcap is basically combination of lighting + materials. To create one you will need to make material, setup lightning, render it to .exr (in 2.8) than add it as a matcap. So your question now is kind a out of place. It's redundant to made matcaps being affected by lights because light is integral part of matcap itself. Take a look here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/call-for-content-matcaps/737/ somebody even posted there scene ready for making matcaps.

Answer (score 3):

A matcap will never respond to lighting -  it's a 'fake' ... a self-lit reflection map of an spherical environment that isn't there. In fact, in effect, it's a 'reflection' of *half* a sphere (infinitely large), directly behind the camera. So if you shade a sphere with a matcap, it will always look exactly like the matcap texture, wherever you look at it from.

In Blender 2.8, you could render the matcap texture you like on a sphere, and in any image-editing application, rotate the texture in 2D. Then, as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/NPCxUKrUzfM?t=142), put the edited image in a 'matcap' folder on the right path. Using it would  have the effect of spinning the 'light source' in the plane of the screen, but would never allow you to bring the 'light' further to the front or back of the 'lit' object.

Perhaps a more fruitful approach would be to create your own matcap - using this kind of setup:

[image]

..which is lifted directly from Cédric Lepiller's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKpDEwy2eLk) on how to create matcaps.. it's not too hard.. no baking, just rendering a sphere. Then at least, you could adjust the 2D rotation in the mapping node, and not have to go to an outside application to do that.

**However**. Having said all this, it would be much better to create your own toon shader tree. (Another question.) Then you could arrange your own lights, and do all sorts of useful things for painting like adjusting the tonal ranges covered by the bands of shade on the surface of your model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time, in future if we could add a simple lighting tool over some special material for sculpting like Zbrush that would be great!