# How do you create matcap shading yourself?

Tags: texturing, shaders, matcaps

Just a general question I can't seem to find the answer to online.  Matcap shading gives a soft shadow I want for my texture, but I see it's either one or the other, you haven't have it with textures.

Is it impossible to have it with textures due to some lighting contradictions?  I assume if you can do this, it'd be in cycles with composite nodes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want a matcap-shader (a flat emission texture baking in the light), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/115118/35559) might help, along with the 2nd linked video

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Matcaps that come with blender in your renders, you can add them as an HDRI. Go to your shader tab, select "World" on the left side (blocked by the file manager window in my image - switch it from "Object"), and add an *Environment Texture*. Click the choose image button, and navigate to `\2.90\datafiles\studiolights\matcap\` (or whatever version you're using). The files (.exr) are all in that folder. Choose the one you like.

[image: Matcaps]

This will provide the lighting and reflections from the image, but will also make it display as a background as well. If you don't want the background image component, just mis it with a regular background, using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* node as a mix factor.

[image: BackgroundGone]

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work..  Please see my updated result.

Comment: It looks like you added an _Image Texture_, instead of an _Environment Texture_. It should say "equirectangular" where it says "flat" on the node in your image.